# Reverse of Silverstripe /dev/build

Tags: silverstripe

Is there a way to get silverstripe to generate Dataobjects from an existing schema? Sort of the reverse to /dev/build

I have an existing project which I want to migrate to Silverstripe, unfortunately this means creating Dataobject classes for 30+ tables.

Either no one has ever done this or my google foo is not that good?

Being a dev, Im sure I could automate this myself but I'm debating if it will be any quicker than just creating them manually?

Comment: I don't know a module which will do that for you, but it should be feasible, at least for simple properties: Get the column name from the schema and set the right data type. It's definitely more complicated with foreign keys, especially m:n, but it should be doable as well. However, unless you'll need this kind of feature on a regular basis, I don't think the effort required will pay off

Comment: Thanks for your comment... Bugger, I was hoping someone knew of a module in existence. 

Indeed, I will have to weigh up if the effort is worth it before implementing one myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's actually a way to do what you want, and I'm not sure it's technically feasable. 
Anyway there's SilverSmith module that can help you in this task, it can generate code from a YAML file: https://github.com/unclecheese/SilverSmith

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to SilverSmith, looks interesting. 
Now I am wondering if it will be easier to build Silverstripe Dataobjects from sql DESCRIBE statements, or if it would be easier to make a YAML file for each table and let SilverSmith generate my classes

Comment: Building Silverstripe Dataobjects from sql DESCRIBE statements could be pain if there's a lot of has_one, has_many and many_many relations. 
If you can develop a tool for code generation you could publish it in http://addons.silverstripe.org/ it may be useful for the community. Good luck!

Comment: After playing around, I have decided it is going to be far more efficient to manually prototype my objects in yml and let SilverSmith work its magic. As noted, the time its going to take to convert sql DESCRIBE results to SS DataObjects or SilverSmiths yml files is going to take alot longer then just doing it manually. I'm still keen to investigate automating it one day, but it will have to wait until I have some more time. Thanks all!